# How to get data in standard error output using AppleScript shell

Tags: swift, macos, applescript

I have the following function:

```
func executeCommandAsAdminWithAppleScript(command: String, inout output: String?, inout errorDesc: String?) -> Bool {
    var errorInfo: NSDictionary?
    let source = "do shell script \"\(command)\" with administrator privileges"
    let script = NSAppleScript(source: source)
    let eventResult = script?.executeAndReturnError(&errorInfo)

    if eventResult == nil {
        errorDesc = nil
        if let code = errorInfo?.valueForKey(NSAppleScriptErrorNumber) as? NSNumber {
            if code.intValue == -128 {
                errorDesc = "The administrator password is required to do this.";
            }

            if errorDesc == nil {
                if let message = errorInfo?.valueForKey(NSAppleScriptErrorMessage) as? NSString {
                    errorDesc = String(message)
                }
            }
        }
        return false
    } else {
        output = (eventResult?.stringValue)!
        return true
    }
}
```

This function basically runs a command with admin privileges. Now I try to execute commands like `echo Hello World`, the `output` parameter does have a string that looks like `Hello World`, which is outputted into `stdout`. But when I tried to execute commands that output data into `stderr`, the output cannot retrieve the data. So is there a way to retrieve data in `stderr` without using NSTask? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe set `command` to `command 2>&1` so it returns both stdout and stderr.

Comment: @MarkSetchell thanks, you can post this as an answer now

Comment: Sure, I have done - glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you use `command` in your script, try replacing it with

```
command 2>&1
```

as that will combine the *standard error* stream (2) with the *standard out* stream (1) and then you will get them both returned to you.